# IE11 pseudo element inline after text

Tags: css, internet-explorer

How can I set this so that Our Services is on one line, problem is IE tested using version 11
[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbNGMG

CSS:

```
ul.megamenu {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
ul.megamenu > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 18px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 16px;
    width: auto;
}
ul.megamenu > li > a {
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: -6px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 12px 7px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
ul.megamenu > li > a span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:before {
    background: none;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:right` from the style. (to make it go right, use `::after` instead of `::before`) And then do a `vertical-align: middle;` because it is `inline-block`.

*Relevant CSS:*

```
ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong::after {
    /* Use after pseudo-element to make it go right */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* float: right; -- Not Required, because we are using the "::after" */
}
```

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v2r7vabj/1/***

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS changes should fix this:

- Change `ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:before` to `ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:after` to place the element after the text
- Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:after` to align it to the middle of the text
- Remove `float: right;` from `ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:after` as it is not needed if you have `display: inline-block;`

```css
ul.megamenu {
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
ul.megamenu > li {
    float: left;
    margin: 18px 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 16px;
    width: auto;
}
ul.megamenu > li > a {
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: -6px 0 0;
    padding: 10px 12px 7px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out 0s;
}
ul.megamenu > li > a span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul.megamenu > li.with-sub-menu > a > span > strong:after {
    background: none;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent;
    border-image: none;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 4px;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<ul class="megamenu">
 <li class="">
  <a href="">
   <span>
    <strong>Home</strong>
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="">
  <a href="">
   <span>
    <strong>Our Products</strong>
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="with-sub-menu">
  <a href="">
   <span>
    <strong>Our Services</strong>
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="">
  <a class="clearfix" href="">
   <span>
    <strong>Contact Us</strong>
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPJREy